# Create a user in centos 5 from a jsp form

Tags: linux, shell, jsp, centos5

I have a form which sends by post method registration.jsp file, first saved in the database and then must open a "command.sh":

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*,java.io.*"%>
<%
   String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(uname, pass, regdate) values ('" + user + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");

  Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./command.sh "+user+pwd);
        if (i > 0) {
              response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
     } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
```

I am using the following code, but when I run it I get an error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYBwV.png)

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4gUc.png)

Yes save in the database.
I also do not know how to create a Unix user by receiving the data I sent from the jsp.

Please Help Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ServletContext.getRealPath()`, for example:

```
String fullPath = application.getRealPath("command.sh");
String[] cmd = { fullPath + " " + user + pwd };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```